# Adding gradle to PATH variable using python 2.7 on Centos 7

Tags: python-2.7, gradle, centos7

I'm new to python and I've been working on a script that will automatically set up development environments. So i have a laundry list of things I need to add to the script and one of them is the latest gradle-5.4.1. I'm running into an issue when I try to add gradle into $PATH on Centos7. After I run this function and run a gradle -v and check the $PATH, it's never concatenated into PATH variable. We need to be able to run gradle from anywhere and I cant seem to figure out how to do this.

```
def install_gradle():
    print("Initiating gradle 5.4.1 install.....")
    os.system("sudo wget https://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-5.4.1-bin.zip -P /tmp")
    os.system("sudo unzip -d /opt/gradle /tmp/gradle-5.4.1-bin.zip")
    os.environ("export PATH=$PATH:/opt/gradle/gradle-5.4.1/bin")
```

I've tried that last line with both os.system and os.environ, neither worked so not sure how to get this to work using python.

Thanks in advance for any input.

Answer (score 0):

So this is what worked for me, editing the bashrc file seemed to resolve the my question:

```
def install_gradle():
print("Initiating gradle 5.4.1 install.....")
print("Downloading gradle file to tmp directory")
os.system("sudo wget https://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-5.4.1-bin.zip -P /tmp")
print("Unzipping gradle installation to /opt/gradle")
os.system("sudo unzip -d /opt/gradle /tmp/gradle-5.4.1-bin.zip")
print("Changing directories to /etc/bashrc")
bashrc_file = open("/etc/bashrc", "a+")
print("Appending PATH environment variables to bashrc file")
bashrc_file.write("export PATH=/opt/gradle/gradle-5.4.1/bin:$PATH")
bashrc_file.close()
```